# Displaying multiple lists of data in a view (i.e. CustomerContacts, CustomerLocations)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, controller, asp.net-mvc-5, repository

I have a CustomersController and in the Detail.cshtml view I need to display a list of that Customer's contacts and a list of that Customer's locations. I have a Detail(int? id) ActionResult and I have access to my CustomerService from within the controller. As of now in my Detail ActionResult I am able to do:

```
var cust = _custService.GetCustomerById(id);
return View(cust);
```

How would one recommend getting the rest of my lists in the view. I think I will create a GetContacts(customerID), GetLocations(CustomerID) within my CustomerService and then call them just like I call GetCustomerByID above. If I were to do it this way how would I have access to these lists in my view.

The next thing I was thinking about was possibly creating a ViewModel that has all of the basic customer properties like customer.Name, customer.Phone but then trying to figure out how I also make sure the ViewModel has the customer's contacts and locations. Would I just add 2 more properties to the ViewModel like customer.contacts and customer.locations since EF6 will make them available to me?

Any suggestions on the best way to go about getting multiple lists of information related to an entity in a view? Customer contacts and Customer locations are both one-to-many

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is using a view model to transfer the data, as you have thought about.

```
public class CustomerDetailViewModel {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public List<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This makes complete sense, thank you for the response. Although, I don't fully understand how adding these Lists properties to my view model will actually give me access to an Individual customer's locations and contacts. For example, if I do customer.GetByID(1) and then do var contacts = customer.Contacts how in the world is this handled automatically? By the way I am using EF6DfFirst but I created individual Dto's which everything actually uses. Rather than creating a view model should these lists properties simply be in my Dtos/POCOs from the start?

Comment: It should be inside of Dto from the start. But when you only want to access some properties from the Customer model, a view model is good approach. You can read more about it here: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/188/view-model-design-and-use-in-razor-views

Comment: Thanks! should it be a virtual property or an actual list?